# Google App Script Auto Reply between hours

Tags: google-apps-script

I have very limited experience with coding, so I appreciate everyone's help. I used a code generator to create an after hours automatic text reply for Google Voice via Google App Script. It responds via e-mail. The code works great! But now I need to create a second auto reply for in between certain hours. The code generator I used doesn't have that capability. This code is one line showing the time triggers. I need the new triggers to be between 12:30 and 18. Can anyone help? TIA

```
function autoreplyCheck() {
  var autoreplyMessage = "Thank you for contacting me! I am currently unavailable. My business hours are Wednesday through Saturday from 8 am until 10 pm. I will return your message by the end of the next business day. If you are a new customer please fill out my new customer form here https://forms.gle/8yPbFAe2vSmXhG3i6";
  var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
  var d = new Date();
  var hour = d.getHours();
  var day = days[d.getDay()];
  var minute = d.getMinutes();
  var currentlyClosed = isClosed(day, hour, minute);
  Logger.log("Currently closed: " +currentlyClosed);
  if (currentlyClosed) {
    var newestThreads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,7);
    for (var i = 0; i < newestThreads.length; i++) {
      if (newestThreads[i].getFirstMessageSubject().search("New text message from") != -1){
        var alreadyReplied = false;
        var textedWhileClosed = false;
        var justCameIn = false;
        var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(newestThreads[i]);
        if (messages[messages.length-1].getPlainBody().search(autoreplyMessage) != -1){
          alreadyReplied = true;
        }
        if (d - messages[messages.length-1].getDate() <= 5 * 60 * 1000){
          justCameIn = true;
        }
        var sentMinute = messages[messages.length-1].getDate().getMinutes();
        var sentHour = messages[messages.length-1].getDate().getHours();
        var sentDay  = messages[messages.length-1].getDate().getDay();
        if (isClosed(days[sentDay], sentHour, sentMinute)){
          textedWhileClosed = true;
        }
        if (!alreadyReplied && textedWhileClosed && justCameIn){
          Logger.log("Sending message!");
          messages[messages.length-1].reply(autoreplyMessage);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function isClosed(day, hour, minute){
  if (day == 'Monday' && (hour < 8 || (hour == 8 && minute < 0) || hour >= 22 || (hour == 22 && minute >= 0))){
    return true;
  } else if (day == 'Tuesday' && (hour < 8 || (hour == 8 && minute < 0) || hour >= 22 || (hour == 22 && minute >= 0))){
    return true;
  } else if (day == 'Wednesday' && (hour < 8 || (hour == 8 && minute < 0) || hour >= 22 || (hour == 22 && minute >= 0))){
    return true;
  } else if (day == 'Thursday' && (hour < 8 || (hour == 8 && minute < 0) || hour >= 22 || (hour == 22 && minute >= 0))){
    return true;
  } else if (day == 'Friday' && (hour < 8 || (hour == 8 && minute < 0) || hour >= 22 || (hour == 22 && minute >= 0))){
    return true;
  } else if (day == 'Saturday' && (hour < 8 || (hour == 8 && minute < 0) || hour >= 20 || (hour == 20 && minute >= 0))){
    return true;
  } else if (day == 'Sunday' && (hour < 8 || (hour == 8 && minute < 0) || hour >= 22 || (hour == 22 && minute >= 0))){
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. Note: You might have to start by learning the JavaScript basics including literals, variables, comparison operators, Boolean operators and the if estatment.

Comment: Do you mean you want to trigger an auto reply anytime between 12:30 and 18:00? Also, could you attach more snippet of your code?

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I have tried this line which didn't work. I don't know if order matters. So if I have to have the less than before the greater than article in the line. Or if it's something else.    else if (day == 'Thursday' && (hour > 12 || (hour == 12 && minute > 30) || hour <= 18 || (hour == 18 && minute <= 0))){
return true

Comment: Yes I want the auto reply to trigger between 12:30 and 18. I uploaded the full code in the original post (it's too long for a comment).

Comment: I looked through some of the other comments on here about GAS and google voice. All of the threads I have seen are either for whole day auto replies or after hours. Both of those the code generator I used could do. I did find one that showed how to do a "between these times" auto reply but the references for the days and times were very different and I'm not strong enough in coding to use that information.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've understood, you want additional time range to `isClosed` function to catch messages from 12:30 - 18:00.

To fix that, you can add this:

```
if(day == 'Thursday' && (hour > 12 || hour === 12 && minute >= 30) && (hour < 18 || hour === 18 && minute <= 0)){
  return true;
}
```

or if you want to apply it to all days,

```
function isClosed(day, hour, minute){
  
  var isInTimeRange = (hour > 12 || hour === 12 && minute >= 30) && (hour < 18 || hour === 18 && minute <= 0);

  if (day == 'Monday' && (( hour < 8 || (hour == 8 && minute < 0) || hour >= 22 || (hour == 22 && minute >= 0)) || isInTimeRange )){
    return true;
  } else if (day == 'Tuesday' && (( hour < 8 || (hour == 8 && minute < 0) || hour >= 22 || (hour == 22 && minute >= 0)) || isInTimeRange )){
    return true;
  } else if (day == 'Wednesday' && (( hour < 8 || (hour == 8 && minute < 0) || hour >= 22 || (hour == 22 && minute >= 0)) || isInTimeRange )){
    return true;
  } else if (day == 'Thursday' && (( hour < 8 || (hour == 8 && minute < 0) || hour >= 22 || (hour == 22 && minute >= 0)) || isInTimeRange )){
    return true;
  } else if (day == 'Friday' && (( hour < 8 || (hour == 8 && minute < 0) || hour >= 22 || (hour == 22 && minute >= 0)) || isInTimeRange )){
    return true;
  } else if (day == 'Saturday' && (( hour < 8 || (hour == 8 && minute < 0) || hour >= 20 || (hour == 20 && minute >= 0)) || isInTimeRange )){
    return true;
  } else if (day == 'Sunday' && (( hour < 8 || (hour == 8 && minute < 0) || hour >= 22 || (hour == 22 && minute >= 0)) || isInTimeRange )){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! I really appreciate all the help :)